# Why my code corrupt a stack? How can I fix it?

Tags: c, stack

I need to make program which can change a decimal, which have range of unsigned char.
I made code, but I the type of 'number' variable makes problems. I think I should not declare the number as a integer type variable for the constraint of this question...so How should I solve it?How can I make my program not to corrupt stack of 'number' variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N_size 8
int main(void) {
    unsigned char number;
    int bin[N_size] = { 0 };
    printf("Input a decimal number of which range of unsigned char:"); 
    scanf("%d", &number);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        bin[N_size-1-i] = number % 2; number = number / 2;

    }
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        printf("%d", bin[j]);

}
```

Comment: This is my code

Answer (score 0):

I think stack got corrupted because u used "%d" when number variable has unsigned char type. U can change it to "%ud" but I don't think that it will help. Besides that you can make use of union data structure. Union shares memory for all of its content. I wrote program about this problem some time ago:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct bits
{
       unsigned char bit0 : 1;
       unsigned char bit1 : 1;
       unsigned char bit2 : 1;
       unsigned char bit3 : 1;
       unsigned char bit4 : 1;
       unsigned char bit5 : 1;
       unsigned char bit6 : 1;
       unsigned char bit7 : 1;
};
union dectobin
{
    unsigned int value;
    struct bits bit;
};

int main()
{
    union dectobin w;
    int s;
    printf("Input a decimal number :");
    s=scanf("%ud",&(w.value));
    if(s!=1)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",(w.bit.bit7),(w.bit.bit6),(w.bit.bit5),(w.bit.bit4),(w.bit.bit3),(w.bit.bit2),(w.bit.bit1),(w.bit.bit0));
    return 0;
}
```